# Caching with Instance Variable in ruby with expired_after like feature 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I'm developing a ruby application ( not a rails one ), I'm looking for a very simple way to cache some of the frequently used results. as for example :

```
 @users ||= User.all
```

Now this is working perfectly but I'm looking for a way to add something like **expire** option that will refresh the command each period of time . in other words I need the same action to be performed in each slice of time or after a number of times . I remember that in rails I used to run memcached and use something like :expire or :expired_at .

Any help would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
class Class
  # create a method whose return value will be cached for "cache_for" seconds
  def cached_method(method,cache_for,&body)
    define_method("__#{method}__".to_sym) do |*a,&b|
      body.call(*a,&b)
    end
    class_eval(<<METHOD)
      def #{method}(*a,&b)
        unless @#{method}_cache && (@#{method}_expiry > Time.now)
          @#{method}_cache  = __#{method}__(*a,&b)
          @#{method}_expiry = Time.now + #{cache_for}
        end
        @#{method}_cache
      end
METHOD
  end
end
```

You can use it like:

```
class MyClass
  cached_method(:users,60) do
    User.all
  end
end
```

This will cache the users for 60 seconds. If you call `users` again on the same object after 60 or more seconds pass, it will execute the method body again and update the cache.

Comment: Supper . thanks alot alex , it's just what i'm looking for , very appreciated . cheers

Answer (score 1):

Don't u think the above one is a little bit complicated  ?

I was trying something like :

```
Cache ={}
def fetch(key, ttl)
  obj, timestamp = Cache[key.to_sym]
  if obj.nil? || Time.now - timestamp > ttl
    obj = yield
    Cache[key]=[obj, now]
  end 
  obj
end
```

I would love to hear your comment about this one

Comment: This method has caveat of uncontrolled memory leak. As only one constant variable is used. Even if Cache.delete :key in else condition will be used, it must be checked. One more, method is not thread safe.